# Removing Subscriber from Suppression list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, subscriber, suppressionlist

Im trying to remove a subscriber from a suppression list, but when i execute the code, i get the status code as "OK" but the subscriber is not getting removed from the suppression list. Any idea what the issue is?

```
    %%[
SET @Sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
        SetObjectProperty(@Sub,"EmailAddress","abhishek.j.mishra@xxx.com")
        SetObjectProperty(@Sub, "SubscriberKey","00Q0n000003NBMCEA4")

SET @objPubList = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
   SetObjectProperty(@objPubList, "Status", "Active")
   SetObjectProperty(@objPubList, "ID", "3909")
   SetObjectProperty(@objPubList, "Action", "delete")
   AddObjectArrayItem(@sub, "Lists", @objPubList)
SET @statusCode = InvokeDelete(@sub, @statusMsg, @errorCode)
]%%

%%=v(@statusCode)=%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. So, at the time of creating a SubscriberList object. You need to set a property as "Action is delete" and use InvokeUpdate instead of InvokeDelete.

```
  %%[
SET @Sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
        SetObjectProperty(@Sub,"EmailAddress","abhishek.j.mishra@xxx.com")
        SetObjectProperty(@Sub, "SubscriberKey","00Q0n000003NBMCEA4")

SET @objPubList = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
   SetObjectProperty(@objPubList, "ID", "3909")
   SetObjectProperty(@objPubList, "Action", "delete")
   AddObjectArrayItem(@sub, "Lists", @objPubList)
SET @statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@sub, @statusMsg, @errorCode)
]%%

%%=v(@statusCode)=%%
```